# How to insert a link into Node.js officegen table

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using a popular Node.js lib to generate MS office word document.

The following code generates a table in [officegen](https://github.com/Ziv-Barber/officegen),
If you provide a raw string to val prop inside the table it generates the text, but how would you provide link?

Tried with creating a paragraph and enhancing it to a link but to no avail.

```
let pObj = docx.createP();
linkObj = pObj.addText('link', { link: 'http://www.google.com' });

const titleCell = (cellValue) => ({
        val: cellValue,
        opts: {
            cellColWidth: 2500,
            b: true,
            sz: '12',
            fontFamily: 'Times New Roman'
        }
    })

 const table = [
        [titleCell('name'), titleCell(linkObj)],
 ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forked the repo and added the needed code to produce a hyperlink inside a table cell

1. go to o*fficegen/lib/docx/docxtable.js*
2. insert the following line of code

```
if (opts.targetLink) {
    relsApp.push({
      type:
        'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/hyperlink',
      target: opts.targetLink,
      targetMode: 'External'
    })
    const linkNum = relsApp.length

    cellObj['w:tc']['w:p']['w:r'] = {
      '@w:rsidRPr': '00722E63',
      'w:rPr': {
        'w:rFonts': {
          '@w:ascii': 'Times New Roman',
          '@w:hAnsi': 'Times New Roman'
        },
        'w:color': {
          '@w:val': '0000EE'
        },
        'w:b': { '@w:val': 0 },
        'w:u': { '@w:val': 'single' },
        'w:sz': {
          '@w:val': '26'
        }
      },
      'w:hyperlink': {
        '@r:id': 'rId' + linkNum,
        'w:t': { '#text': multiLineBreakObj }
      }
    }
  }
```

3. when defining a table, use it by inserting the targetLink property

```
   var table = [
      [{
          val: 'No.',
          opts: {
            cellColWidth: 4261,
            color: '7F7F7F',
            b: true,
            sz: '14',
            fontFamily: 'Arial'
          }
        },
        {
          val: 'Title1',
          opts: {
            targetLink: 'https://www.google.com/',
            b: true,
            color: '7F7F7F',
            align: 'right'
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
```

You can also download the forked repo on my github: https://github.com/eugensunic/officegen

Include it in your *package.json* as follows:

`"officegen": "git+https://github.com/eugensunic/officegen.git"`
and run *npm install*